# Summernote custom CSS

Tags: summernote

i'm using [summernote](http://summernote.github.io/summernote/) in my CMS to edit content. The CMS is used for multiple customers.

How can I link to the css of each customer? So the "style"-dropdown will show their own headings?
Tnx!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus

Surf to any of the links on the left, like the documentation:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus.Editor?http://cdn.xportability.com/Samples/NimbusDoc.html.

This uses a customized version of Summernote (we are porting to the latest) that reads specific files and creates a "Class" insertion popdown for specific classes that could be included. This is all built in Javascript.

You can certainly get all of that Javascript and look through it as to how we insert custom classes and apply them on selection. You could apply the same technique to replace the "style" dropdown with your own that is styled using the customer-applied CSS.

[image: Nimbus Class Extension]

Comment: Tnx Kevin, where can I find the javascript?

Comment: Well. You can hit that page and examine the JS used. We are gathering this all together to post to Github soon as a complete library but in the meantime you can easily do that.